# Software to create trees like hand-drawn

Tags: mind-mapping, tree-view

What software could I use to **rapidly** and **easily** create trees like this:

[image: Tree of thoughts]

Looking for freeware. Please supply screenshots where possible. Mind maps are OK as soon as they look like a tree.

**Windows** and/or **Linux**. **Web-based** is great!

Comment: Pen and Paper? :P

Answer (score 9):

**[FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)** is a premier free mind-mapping software written in Java. (and thus works on all platforms where the Java Runtimes are installed).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for, but [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is good for producing graphs.

[image]

It's actually a text format. Here's the code that produced the picture:

```
digraph SomeTrees {

node  [fontsize=10];

Root -> Item
Root -> "One more item"
"One more item" -> Subitem

Fruit -> Apple
Fruit -> Microsoft
Fruit -> Google

}
```

Comment: Neat little program!

Comment: Graphiz and Gliffy are great alternatives to Visio.